# No se me envían los datos con React.js y axios

Tags: php, reactjs

Estoy intentando realizar un CRUD (por primera vez) con React y PHP. Para esto, estoy utilizando axios. Mi primer error era que el CORS no me permitía recibir los datos. Ya lo pude resolver de esta manera:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == "OPTIONS") {

    die();

}

echo $_POST['nombre'];

?>
```

El problema está en el echo. Cuando lo envío a este archivo, me indica que el índice 'nombre' es indefinido. Quisiera saber porqué no se está enviando el objeto. El componente de React es este:

```
//Importar React.
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";

//Importar Estilos.

//Importar librerías / frameworks.
import axios from 'axios';

//Importar componentes.
import Enlaces from './navbar';

class Insertar extends Component {

    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.state = {

            nombre: '',
            apellido: '',
            correo: ''

        }

    }

    onChangeNombres(e) {

        this.setState({

            nombre: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onChangeApellidos(e) {

        this.setState({

            apellido: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onChangeCorreo(e) {

        this.setState({

            correo: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onSubmit(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        const nuevoUsuario = {

            nombre: this.state.nombre,
            apellido: this.state.apellido,
            correo: this.state.correo,

        };

        axios.post('http://localhost/reactjscrud/ingresar/index.php', { nuevoUsuario }).then( res => { console.log(res.data) } ).catch( e => { console.log(e) } );

        this.state = {

            nombre: '',
            apellido: '',
            correo: ''

        }

    }

    render(){

        return(

            <Fragment>

                <Enlaces/>

                <div className="container" style={{marginTop: 10}}>

                    <h3>Agregar nuevo usuario</h3>

                    <br/>

                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="nombreUsuario">Nombres:</label>

                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" id="nombreUsuario" placeholder="Nombres del usuario..." value={this.state.nombre} onChange={(e) => this.onChangeNombres(e)} autocomplete="off" />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="apellidoUsuario">Apellidos:</label>

                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="apellidoUsuario" id="apellidoUsuario" placeholder="Apellidos del usuario..." value={this.state.apellido} onChange={(e) => this.onChangeApellidos(e)} autoComplete="off" />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="correoUsuario">Correo electrónico:</label>

                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="correoUsuario" id="correoUsuario" placeholder="Correo electrónico del usuario..." value={this.state.correo} onChange={(e) => this.onChangeCorreo(e)} autoComplete="off" />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <button type="submit" value="Regitrar" name="botonRegistrar" className="btn btn-success">Subir</button>

                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </Fragment>

        );

    }

}

export default Insertar;
```

Agradecería mucho si me pudieran ayudar, pues he intentado muchas cosas, pero no he podido.

Comment: Lo que estas enviando hacia tu API es un objeto, no una propiedad. Ten en cuenta eso.

Comment: ¿Y cómo enviaría las propiedades de esos 3 campos?

Comment: Revisa si realmente se estan enviando todos los campos. Ve al navegador y en opciones de desarrollador o inspeccionar, network o redes, y revisa tu petición. En la subpestaña que se abre, debe decir params y ahí deberias poder ver lo que estas enviando. Porque estas enviando un objeto que tiene dentro un objeto con las propiedades.

Prueba quitandole los brackets a nuevoUsuario en la llamada al axios

Comment: No. No me aparece ninguna opción de params (Google chrome). Por otro lado, ya pude confirmar que sí es un objeto.

Comment: Esta bien que lo envíes como un Objeto, pero al momento de realizar `echo $_POST['nombre'];` estas tratando de obtener el valor de una propiedad *nombre* que no existe. Podrias usar [get_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-object-vars.php) por ejemplo :)

Comment: Estoy intentándolo ya, ¿Pero cómo podría hacer para enviar parámetros y no un objeto?

Comment: Mmmm... no te lo recomiendo, porque seria algo engorroso enviar tantas propiedades cuando se puede crear un objeto que las encapsule todas. Animo! No solo se trata que funcione, sino que funcione de forma eficiente tambien. Trata con lo que te envie y nos comentas como te fue

Comment: El problema es que esta línea 'var_dump(get_object_vars($nombreUsuario));' no em funciona. también lo intenté así 'var_dump(get_object_vars($_POST['nombreUsuario']));' y sigue sin funcionar. El error es el mismo.

Comment: Es decir, definitivamente el problema real es que ni siquiera está enviando el objeto.

Comment: Prueba quitando los `{}` al `POST` y deja solo _nuevoUsuario_

Comment: Aún nada. Mismo error. ¿Es completamente necesario usar axios? Veo que a menos a mí, no me funciona. Los datos no son enviados.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107065/discussion-between-paulo-urbano-rivera-and-santiago-correa-aguirre-sanmar).

Answer (score 0):

Existe un solo problema de sintaxis en:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/reactjscrud/ingresar/index.php', { nuevoUsuario })
```

Específicamente en `{nuevoUsuario}`, ya que **nuevoUsuario** ya es inicializado como objeto en:

```
 const nuevoUsuario = {
     nombre: this.state.nombre,
     apellido: this.state.apellido,
     correo: this.state.correo,
 };
```

Entonces estarias enviando algo similar a esto:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/reactjscrud/ingresar/index.php', {{nombre:this.state.nombre,apellido: this.state.apellido,correo: this.state.correo}})
```

Y si notas existen doble llave (un objeto dentro de otro objeto).

La solución es simple

> Quita una de las llaves.

```
axios.post('http://localhost/reactjscrud/ingresar/index.php', {nombre:this.state.nombre,apellido: this.state.apellido,correo: this.state.correo})
```

Problema solucionado.

Comment: La respuesta no es del todo correcta @Nobub, creo que debes revisarla para no confundir a quien pueda dar por válida tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás enviando al servidor de la manera que lo tienes montado en React es lo siguiente:

```
{ nuevoUsuario: { nombre, apellido, correo } };
```

En el servidor tienes que recibir la propiedad `nuevoUsuario` explícitamente y acceder a través de ella a, nombre, apellido y correo.

Si lo que quieres es enviar directamente nombre, apellido y correo y no `nuevoUsuario` haz lo siguiente:

Cambia en la linea: 
`axios.post('http://localhost/reactjscrud/ingresar/index.php', { nuevoUsuario }).then( res => { console.log(res.data) } ).catch( e => { console.log(e) } );`

donde tienes `{ nuevoUsuario }` por `{ ...nuevoUsuario }`

Lo que estás haciendo aquí es destructurar el objeto en sus propiedades.

Puedes consultar los detalles aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment